# Does Azure DevOps Git REST API support adding submodules?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I can't find any reference on this.

Is there support for calling their REST API to add a submodule?

Comment: I ask in ignorant curiosity... Why should you need to add it via the REST API? Submodules are a git concept, right, so I would think the natural place to add them is in the git repository itself.

Comment: I am making a SPA web interface for managing the repository. Unless you know of an in memory JavaScript git client that can run in the browser (if you do I’ll buy you a coffee!) (isomorphic git doesn’t seem to support submodules), I need to use REST APIs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot found related [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) to add submodules.

We can configure the submodules setting in the [Checkout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#checkout) step of your pipeline if you want to download files from submodules.
Sample code:

```
steps:
- checkout: self  # self represents the repo where the initial Pipelines YAML file was found
  clean: boolean  # whether to fetch clean each time
  fetchDepth: number  # the depth of commits to ask Git to fetch
  lfs: boolean  # whether to download Git-LFS files
  submodules: true | recursive  # set to 'true' for a single level of submodules or 'recursive' to get submodules of submodules
  path: string  # path to check out source code, relative to the agent's build directory (e.g. \_work\1)
  persistCredentials: boolean  # set to 'true' to leave the OAuth token in the Git config after the initial fetch
```

Or we can use [git command](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) `git submodule add {url}` to Checkout submodules

**Update1**

We can install PowerShell module posh-git, then we could use git cmd in the power shell. You can refer to the doc [posh-git](https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git#using-posh-git) and [Setting up Git in PowerShell](https://thepracticalsysadmin.com/setting-up-git-in-windows/)

Comment: Thanks but this is for programmatic integration from a client side powershell script.

Comment: Hi @Jeff, we can use the git command in the power shell, you can refer to this [doc](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Appendix-A%3A-Git-in-Other-Environments-Git-in-PowerShell)

Comment: Hi @Jeff, I have update the answer, please check it. Feel free to let me know the latest news.